# How can i set the first day of the week in momentjs library without using locales

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

In software i'm writing there wont be setting page for choosing locale. I'll offer my users only date format and the way for them to choose what day of week will be considered as first day of the week.

Is there a way i can set a day of the week for momentjs so momentjs always use that setting when doing all calculations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution to this issue, which i consider a hack. Basically it all comes to locale, and to be more precise we need to customise the default one (en).

```
var first_day_of_week = 5;

moment.locale('en', {
  week : {
    dow : first_day_of_week,
    doy : moment.localeData('en').firstDayOfYear()
  }
});
```

We initialize the 'en' locale with new locale definition where we change only the **week.dow** parameter. We need also to supplement **week.doy** param or it will be reset to **undefined**.

Other locale data, like month names, days of the week, relative dates will be inherited from the default locale (which is in our case the same locale we're customising)

This is tested and momentjs acknowledges the changes we're made. I know it's not the prettiest way to do this, but it works.